# How I can save and use file locally in iphone application developed in AS3?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex4.5

In a iPhone application developed with adobe air, I must save permanently from web to device some files (image or pdf). 
For example for me is important that the files are not deleted when the app is closed or re-opened.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the applicationStorageDirectory. Take a look here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html

This might be useful, as well:
http://halcyonsolutions.net/presos/08/airsql/080326-eSeminar-Adobe_AIR_Local_Data_Storage.pdf